# Disparar evento 'click' en elementos clonados en el DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy construyendo un serie de `select multiple` que clono de una matrís básica.

Inicialmente creo uno y a medida que se selecciona una `option` de la lista se va creando un par `Nombre`:`Valor` dinámicamente. Hasta aquí todo bien.

Luego necesito usando un botón `+` crear nuevos `select multiple` partiendo nuevamente de la matrís inicial. Todo esto en una modal de Bootstrap.

El problema está en que a partir del segundo elemento clonado, que son creados usando el botón de `+`, no se crean los pares `Nombre`:`Valor` que necesito.

El resultado debe ser algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dije, el código me funciona para el primer clone que lo construyo en el momento de abrir la modal, pero las siguiente que se añaden a partir del clic en el botón `+` no:

```
$('#cloned-access-level .access-level.level-cloned').each(function(){
    var item    = $(this)
        list    = item.find('select[name="adviser"]')

    list.on('change', function(){
        ...
    })
})
```

Supongo que lo que debo hacer es hacer que este código funcione sobre los elementos clonados, pero no lo logro.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas un nuevo elemento a partir de un script, las funciones que defines no los afectan si quieres acceder a ellas directamente, este es un ejemplo:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function(){
  $('.wrap').append('<li class="item">Item '+($('.item').length+1) +'</li>');
});

$('.item').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  list-style: none;
}

.item{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.active{
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrap">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
</ul>
<button class="add">Add item</button>
```

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar el evento al documento y pasar como [selector](https://api.jquery.com/on/) lo que quieres que active el evento:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function(){
  $('.wrap').append('<li class="item">Item '+($('.item').length+1) +'</li>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrap{
  list-style: none;
}

.item{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.active{
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrap">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
</ul>
<button class="add">Add item</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado perfecto, aunque ahora tengo otros problemillas pero ando trabajando en ellos +1